# Stratified data set in R

Tags: r

I need help with creating a a new dataframe. I have a dataframe of which i need to pull the same 100 samples from. But this data must have the same proportion of males and females as the original dataset. How can i keep the proportion the same?

PTData looks like this

PTNumb .   Sex .  Age . SysbP . SMoke . ...

1 .          M .    12 .  76 .   N

2 .      F .      13 .  89 .   Y

PTData has 5000 sets of data. I need to pull 100 with the portion of male being 0.46 and female is 0.54 and store as new dataframe.

I don't want to use the stratified function which i originally did.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` tools, it should be something like this. I am assuming the given ratio of 0.46 male to 0.54 female is the existing dataset ratio, since that is what you said you wanted. In future, it is good to look up previous resources and provide an example dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
sampled <- PTData %>%
    group_by(Sex) %>%
    sample_n(size = 100)
```

EDIT: using base functions, you can do this more manually:

```
m <- PTData[Sex == "M", ]
f <- PTData[Sex == "F", ]
sample_m <- m[sample(1:nrow(m), size = 46), ]
sample_f <- f[sample(1:nrow(f), size = 54), ]
sampled <- rbind(sample_m, sample_f)
```

Comment: I apologize. Thank you for your help but i'm not allowed to download other packages

Comment: Why don't you subset your data into men and women, then randomly sample 46 observations of men and 54 of women? `?sample`

Comment: I already have 2 subsets for the M and F data. How can i add them together into one subset? and even though i want the program to randomly pull 100 datasets, i want it to generate the same data each time so i can still use the seed function right?